# What terminology should we use for product categories and collections?

Tags: terminology

we have an online shop selling different categories of Accessories and Jewellery.
To make the site more accessible and browsable, we have a left column which contains:

Shop by collection

---

handmade jewellery collection
little surprises
leather collections
....

Shop by category

---

bracelets
rings
pendants
....

Question is what terminology works best to make it more user-friendly instead of "Shop by collection"  and "Shop by category"

Thanks

Comment: what does `shop by collection` has?

Comment: Categories and Collections

Comment: or just Categories will be enough to cover entire shopping list

Comment: Not actually. Evey product could belong to different Collections (Wedding collection, outdoor collection, etc) but the same product can only have 1 type (pendant, bracelet, ring, etc)

Comment: see the actual website at http://glorio.com.au

Comment: actually it looks quite okay/intuitive on your website. Any particular concerns you have in mind?

Comment: shop by brand / shop by item type. Have you not opened any other commerce website to get ideas before posting? And I'm sorry to say  but your question sounds a bit like "can you please do my homework"? I would appreciate if you could make it more generic and ask how people who sell collections of specific items can come up with and test terminologies that their own users understand clearly, because this might differ a lot from site to site and language to language, and your question as it is is only useful to you and not future users of the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up against this type of thing before and recommend one of two routes.

1. Either just go down the categories route, but make it possible to have the same product in multiple category, that way you can have pendents appearing in both "Wedding" and "Pendants"
2. Other option to have "Shop by Event" or "Shop by Occasion" or both, allowing people to go in to what you recommend for these specific occasions or events. For example, if it was me and i went on a jewellery site to buy something for my wife for our anniversary, I'd love to know that that piece of jewellery was acceptable for that event as I'm a bit clueless.